# Best and acute Linux for grand pa notebook? - Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu

Is there any Linux to resurrect this old notebook?

==========================

CPU : Pentium III 750Mhz
 RAM : 64MB + 64MB = 128MB
 HDD : 80GB

[HP Compaq Presario 1700]

---

p.s. I have been installing Lubuntu 12.04 since the last night. It is being installed now.

Comment: That is ancient hardware and not likely to be supported by any modern distro. IMO you should look at a micro distro such as tinycore. It will not run fast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly Ubuntu related, but I would recommend Damn Small Linux. [Here's](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/minimum_hardware_requirements.html) the minimum specs for DSL. Scroll to the bottom to view the Recommended Specs.